# Fastest way to reduce a csv file to two columns

Tags: php

I have a csv file that has like 30,000 rows in it.  It also has like 9 columns.  In the interest of speeding up the processing of everything I want to reduce the file to the two columns that I need and remove the rest.  here is what I have done.

```
$retardment=1;//17;// 151;  //499;//  991;// 1877
if (($handle = fopen($source, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $stock_handle = fopen($source_stock, "w+"); 
    $row=0;
    $col=array();
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            unset($line[1]);
            unset($line[2]);
            unset($line[3]);
            unset($line[4]);
            unset($line[5]);
            unset($line[6]);
            unset($line[8]);
            unset($line[9]);
        if($row%$retardment<1){
            fputcsv($stock_handle, $line);
        }
            unset($line);
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($stock_handle);
}
```

I am coping it to a new file and this works... but it seems to be pretty slow.  Any ideas on how to make it faster?  Thank you for the help.

Cheers -Jeremy

**{EDIT}**
So far this seems to take just as long. But works just fine

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if($row%$retardment<1){
        fputcsv($stock_handle, array($line[0],$line[7]));
    }
    $row++;
}
```

Comment: Why not just go through the file line by line, pick out the entries corresponding to the two columns that you **do** want, and write those to the output file?

Comment: I figured that it would gain speed as memory was freed up.

Comment: You're assigning a new array to `$line` throughout each iteration of the `while` loop, so memory usage is prettymuch negligible.  Take what you want and output it.  Don't worry about `unset`ting a bunch of stuff in a loop that you don't care about.

Comment: So not using unset didn't seem to speed it up at all.. I didn't mircotime check on it but it seems to be just as long.  I basicly reduced everything in the while loop down to fputcsv($stock_handle, array($line[0],$line[7])); and it seems just as slow.

Comment: 30K lines takes about 10-15 mins on a 1024gb ram in a 64bit bare bone linux cloud server. About the same time as before. Now to put it in perspective, I can do the same task in about 1.5 mins start to end in excel "by hand". not that anything we do on these boxes are by hand lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace those `unset()` calls with...

```
$line = array($line[0], $line[7]);
```

Alternatively, remember that `unset()` takes multiple arguments...

```
unset($line[1], $line[2], ...);
```

Comment: hmm.. I'll try this.. I was hoping to find a "remove column" type function that was hidden away.  In pratice it's faster for me to open excel and delete the columns and then save it this for this script to run.  But I can't do it by hand all the time lol.

Comment: this was what was used in the final approch as noted above.  Thanks -

Answer (score 0):

You can speed it up fractionally more, but again it's a microtime()-measurable improvement: perception is that it won't be noticeably faster.

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
    if($row++ % $retardment < 1){ 
        fputcsv($stock_handle, array($line[0],$line[7])); 
    } 
}
```

but as your script is IO-bound, it's the actual reads and writes that are the slowest functions, and you can't speed those up.

Using [stream_copy_to_stream()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php) with a [stream input filter](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-filter-register.php) might be another approach, but you won't see much noticeable improvement unless you can reduce disk access times

Comment: So as I see it I'd though I was only accessing the file 4 time, open read, write close per file which there is two... But ... thinking about it.. fputcsv() is writing to the file anit it, so the best thing may be to build what I want to write and store it in memory then write all at once?  may-be?